# CMD How to put DIR's result in variable?

Tags: variables, cmd, set, echo, dir

What I tried to do is put dir in "Answer" variable. The variable's result have nothing inside it. What did I do wrong?

```
@echo off
set /p name=Program name:
echo %name%
set Answer=dir /s /a /b C:\%name%
echo %Answer%
Pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a command line into a variable, but a variable is not intended to hold a page of data.

If you had used this by itself (instead of `echo %answer%`)then it would display the dir output:

```
%answer%
```